# How to get sibling text of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, click

I have `ul` list, in every `li` i have 2 `span` and one `a` tag link and a text for li:

```html
<li>
    <span>first name 1</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name 1</span>email address 1
</li>
<li>
    <span>first name 2</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name 2</span>email address 2
</li>
<!-- 
    multiple li 
-->
<li>
    <span>first name n</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name n</span>email address n
</li>
```

Now if a user select a link in every `li` tag, by jquery i want to get `first name` and `email address` text. I will appreciate to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selector to finding target span and use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to finding sibling text of span.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).prev().text();
    var email = $(this).next()[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
});
```

```css
a {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <span>first name 1</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name 1</span>
    email address 1
</li>
<li>
    <span>first name 2</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name 2</span>
    email address 2
</li>
<li>
    <span>first name n</span>
    <a>//icon to be selected</a>
    <span>last name n</span>
    email address n
</li>
```